# Vowpal Wabbit - badly formatted example, only one line can have a cost (Contextual Bandits)

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, vowpalwabbit

I am new to Vowpal Wabbit. I have successfully tested a VW agent/learner for a small subset of data from a DataFrame (~20 rows). But when I increase the dataset to 2000 rows, I get a formatting error?

The learner I had initated was:

```
vw = pyvw.vw("--cb_explore_adf -q UA --quiet --epsilon 0.2")
```

My data in VW format looks like this:

```
shared |User user=46235223 time_of_day=2020-11-15T12:01:00.000Z
|Action article=politics on world news
|Action article=sports page about football 
|Action article=music about the 80s
|Action article=food regarding veganism
```

Sample of the data:

```
articleId   user    time_of_day            article
0001        1212    02-01-2021-16:06:01    Food regarding veganism                                     
0002        1422    03-01-2021-06:16:32    Sports page about football 
0003        8286    12-08-2021-15:43:05    Music about the 80s
0004        4528    27-11-2021-16:11:09    Food regarding veganism
```

[image: Vowpal Wabbit Formatting Error]

Comment: What version are you using? Can you provide me the dataset so I can look into it?

Comment: The version I am using is vowpalwabbit==8.9.0

I have included a sample of the data (unfortunately can not send due to privacy laws)

Comment: There was a bug in 8.9.0 that behaved like this. Can you please install 8.9.1?

Comment: I don't think version 8.9.1 exists. I get the following error: "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vowpalwabbit==8.9.1"

Comment: My mistake - I was thinking of 8.8.1, you're right 8.9.0 is the most recent Python release. Hmm this kind of bug is often a result of some internal memory reuse which we are actively trying to fix/resolve. It is hard to debug without a repro. Are you able to obtain a repro? Does it repro with all features removed?